# How do I change the working directory in Ada?

Tags: directory, ada, spawn

How do I change the current working directory in Ada?

I would have expected GNAT's OS_Lib to have a chdir procedure, but no such luck.

Of course, spawning a new process running 'cd' is a hopeless endeauvour, at best it would create a new process which itself will live (very briefly) in the given directory.

```pascal
with GNAT.OS_Lib;

procedure main is
   procedure Spawn (Program : String) is
      Empty_Arguments : GNAT.OS_Lib.Argument_List (1..0);
      Exit_Code : constant Integer := GNAT.OS_Lib.Spawn (Program_Name => Program, Args => Empty_Arguments);
   begin
      if Exit_Code /= 0 then
         raise Program_Error with Program & " exited with exit code: " & Exit_Code'Image;
      end if;
   end Spawn;
begin
   Spawn ("cd dir"); -- replace this with the proper way to do this
   Spawn ("make");   -- on windows 'dir' is another command that is dependent on the current directory
end main;
```

The aim is that for the next procedure, make in the above example, the directory has been changed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Set_Directory` (see also [RM A.16 (6)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-16.html#p6)). For example:

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Directories;  use Ada.Directories;
with Ada.Wide_Text_IO; use Ada.Wide_Text_IO;
with Ada.Characters.Conversions;

procedure Main is   
   
   --  Compile with option "-gnatW8" to set wide character encoding to UTF-8.
   
   --------------------
   -- List_Directory --
   --------------------
   
   procedure List_Directory is
      
      use Ada.Characters.Conversions;
      
      Pattern : constant String      := "*.*";      
      Filter  : constant Filter_Type :=
        (Ordinary_File => True, others => False);   --  Files only.
      
      S : Search_Type;
      E : Directory_Entry_Type;
      
   begin      
      Put_Line (To_Wide_String (Current_Directory));
      Put_Line ("["2502"]");
      
      Start_Search (S, Current_Directory, Pattern, Filter);
      while More_Entries (S) loop
         Get_Next_Entry (S, E);
         
         if More_Entries (S) then
            Put ("["251C"]["2500"] ");
         else
            Put ("["2514"]["2500"] ");
         end if;
         Put_Line (To_Wide_String (Simple_Name (E)));
         
      end loop;
      End_Search (S);
      
   end List_Directory;
   
   
begin   
   List_Directory; New_Line;
   
   Set_Directory ("./src");
   List_Directory; New_Line;
   
   Set_Directory ("../obj");
   List_Directory; New_Line;
   
end Main;
```

**output**

```
$ ./obj/main
/home/deedee/foo
│
└─ default.gpr

/home/deedee/foo/src
│
└─ main.adb

/home/deedee/foo/obj
│
├─ gpsauto.cgpr
├─ main.ali
├─ main.bexch
├─ b__main.o
├─ b__main.ali
├─ main.o
├─ main.adb.stderr
├─ main.adb.stdout
├─ b__main.adb
├─ b__main.ads
└─ default-loc.xml
```

Comment: Where can I read a bit about these String literals: "["2502"]" ?

Comment: See the [GNAT User's Guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gnat_ugn/), section [3.2.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gnat_ugn/Wide_005fCharacter-Encodings.html#Wide_005fCharacter-Encodings) (Wide_Character Encodings, Brackets Coding) and section [4.3.11](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gnat_ugn/Character-Set-Control.html#Character-Set-Control) (Character Set Control).

Comment: The value 2502 is the Unicode code point for "box drawings light vertical", which is part of the Unicode Box Drawings block (see, for example, [here](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/2502.html) and [here](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/block/Box_Drawing.html)).

Comment: The brackets coding can also be used in the source code itself, as shown in [`Ada.Numerics`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=gcc/ada/libgnat/a-numeri.ads;hb=HEAD), where it is used to define Pi as a Greek symbol.